# JavaScript : Augmenting Types

Tags: javascript

I'm reading JavaScript:The Good Parts and found below example. I tried to alter the given example but got an error.
This works:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
}
Number.method("add", function(a, b){
    console.log(a+b);
});
var a = new Number();
a.add(2,2);
```

Output:

```
4
```

But the following one does not:

```
Number.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
}
Number.method("add", function(a, b){
    console.log(a+b);
});
var a = new Number();
a.add(2,2);
```

Output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Number.method is not a function
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Number.method <--> Function.method

Comment: @johnSmith I've uploaed a pic. Am I doing the same what you did?

Comment: @Pallav, basically, `Number` is an instance of `Function`, but `Number` is not an instance of `Number`.

Comment: You would have to declare `Number.method = function() {/* ... */}` for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number is an instance of Function, and so it delegates to Function's prototype.

In your altered version, you added `method` to `Number.prototype`, not `Number` - which is a constructor function.

So the `Number.method` that you attempted to call did not exist.

In order for this to work, you would need to change that first line `Number.prototype.method` to `Number.method`.

Comment: What is the meaning of 'Number is an instance of Function'? Does this mean Number.prototype = Function?

Comment: @PallavJha It means that it is an occurrence of something - in this case, a function.

In the context of Javascript, to be an instance of something means to have been created by that particular constructor function. 

A constructor function is simply a function that creates and returns an object of a certain template. For example: `Number` is a constructor _function_, and numbers in JS (`1`, `452`, `56123123`) are all instances of `Number`. Since `Number` is a constructor function, Number itself is an instance of the `Function` constructor.

Comment: The template that determines the shared methods between instances is often defined by the `.prototype` property. The `.prototype` property is an object containing all the shared properties/methods that those instances will 'inherit'. The number `2` in Javascript is said to 'inherit' those methods from Number.prototype, which in this case would be all of Javascript's native Number methods.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/prototype

```
Writable        no
Enumerable      no
Configurable    no
```

Basically you just skip the prototype and do it without it, as `Number` is an instance of `Function`. That is why you can do `Function.prototype.method`! Do it like so:

```js
Number.method = function(name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}
Number.method("add", function(a, b) {
    document.write(a + b);
});
var a = new Number();
a.add(2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way

```
Number.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.__proto__[name] = func;
  return this;
}
var a = new Number();
a.method("add", function(a, b){
    console.log(a+b);
});
a.add(2,2)
```